# vb6 oracle9i application, logical error-recordset remains empty

Tags: vb6, oracle9i, recordset

Currently I am working on a project that forces me to use Vb6 as a front end and Oracle 9i as a backend in my application. I need to retrieve data from a table in oracle, and display it in a VB6 form. Im using a recordset for this, but for some reason it doesnt contain any record even when a valid record is present in the table in question. Can anyone tell me what's wrong? Any help would be appreciated. My code is as follows-

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim sql As String
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
sql = "select test23.phoname from test23 where test23.ops='" + Text1.Text + "'"
rs.Open sql, con, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
If rs.EOF = False Then
    Form7.Show
    Form7.Label2.Caption = rs.Fields("phoname")
End If
End Sub
```

The if statements never execute, as the recordset always seems empty. If I remove the EOF condition I get a runtime error 3021. Is there something wrong with my sql query? The table test23 is already present in my oracle database with attributes serialno, phoname and ops.
Thanks-
      Ron

Comment: I don't use SQL very much, but I've never seen table.field syntax used before.  You're sure it's valid? Have you tried `SELECT phoname FROM test23 WHERE ops='" + Text1.Text + "'"`?

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled through this myself some years ago. The problem could be in several areas: specificaly the connection, the Oracle drivers, the Oracle home or the query itself.

I would strongly recommend that you download the free version of TOAD which will allow you to test both your connection (I assume ODBC of some sort) and you can then execute the query manually using TOAD.

Are you getting any exceptions?

Hopefully from this you can then correct your code/connection/query.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I would also point out that adoOpenStatic and adoLockOptimistic are mutually exclusive property values, as optimistic locking only applies to updatable recordsets and static recordsets aren't updatable (except in batch mode with adoLockBatchOptimistic).  This may be confusing the Oracle OLEDB provider somehow.